# Adding a % to a cost price and creating a new column

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a column of Cost prices and a column for Retail Price but this column is a calculated field, Cost price + 35%, so I want to write a select statement that updates the Retail Price automatically but just cant think how to do it. Can you help.

```
Cost Price      Retail Price
   35
   45
  125
   35

DECLARE @OrderNumber varchar (30)
DECLARE @OrderDate int
DECLARE @OrderLineNumber varchar(50)
DECLARE @CustomerSkey int
DECLARE @ProductSkey int
DECLARE @OrderMethodSkey int
DECLARE @Quantity int
DECLARE @Cost Decimal(18,3)


SET @OrderNumber = 1
SET @OrderDate = 0
SET @OrderLineNumber = 1
SET @CustomerSkey = 1
SET @ProductSkey = 1
SET @OrderMethodSkey = 1
SET @Quantity = 1
SET @Cost = 1


WHILE @OrderNumber <= 100
WHILE @OrderDate <= 100
WHILE @OrderLineNumber <= 100
WHILE @CustomerSkey <= 100
WHILE @ProductSkey <= 100
WHILE @OrderMethodSkey <= 100
WHILE @Quantity <= 100
WHILE @Cost <= 100



BEGIN
INSERT INTO Orders 
(OrderNumber
, OrderDate
, OrderLineNumber
, CustomerSkey
, ProductSkey
, OrderMethodSkey
, OrderTime
, Quantity
, Cost
, Price)

SELECT 
'ORD' + Right ('000000' + CAST (@OrderNumber AS varchar (30)), 6)
,DATEADD (day, CAST (RAND () * 1500 as int), '2008-1-1')
,(Right ('0' + CAST (@OrderLineNumber AS varchar (30)), 6))
,(99 * RAND()) + 1
,(99 * RAND()) + 1
,(2 * RAND()) + 1
,DATEADD(ms, cast(86400000 * RAND() as int), convert(time, '00:00'))
,(190 * RAND()) + 10
,(40 * RAND()) + 10
,@Cost + (@Cost * .35)



SET @OrderNumber = @OrderNumber + 1
SET @OrderDate = @OrderDate + 1
SET @OrderLineNumber = @OrderLineNumber + 1
SET @CustomerSkey = @CustomerSkey + 1
SET @ProductSkey = @ProductSkey + 1
SET @OrderMethodSkey = @OrderMethodSkey + 1
SET @Quantity = @Quantity + 1
SET @Cost = @Cost + 1


END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make it a calculated column with the following formula:

```
CostPrice + (CostPrice * .35)
```

So whenever you insert the new entry to table, the `CostPrice` will automatically evaluated.

Comment: Sorry I should have added the full script please see above.

Comment: just go to table design -> Column Properties -> Computed Column Specification -> formula -> `CostPrice + (CostPrice * .35)`

Comment: I know need to take the Quantity and times it by Price to get the Value, do I do this in the same place?

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE TableName SET RetailPrice = CostPrice + (CostPrice * .35)
```

Comment: Sorry I should have added the full script please see above.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE Orders SET Price = Cost * 1.35
```

Or if you want to make the percent a variable:

```
UPDATE Orders SET Price = Cost * (1 + (@PERCENT / 100))
```

Comment: Sorry I should have added the full script please see above.

Answer (score 0):

If the Retail Price always equals the Cost Price plus some percentage, then you might want to see if a [Computed Column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) will make sense.

Here is an example of a table defined with a computed column

```
CREATE TABLE TableName ( 
    CostPrice DECIMAL(18,4), 
    RetailPrice AS (CostPrice * 1.35)
);
```

However, if you can't define or change the table schema, or just want to update the retail price for selected rows, then when you can use the value of the value in the CostPrice column to update the RetailPrice column.

```
UPDATE TableName SET RetailPrice = CostPrice * 1.35
```

For each row, this will use the CostPrice to set the RetailPrice of the row. You can also include a `WHERE` clause to if you want to limit the rows that get updated, instead of updating every row in the table.